# Is there a null-conditional operator for array concatenation?

Tags: javascript, null-conditional-operator

```js
const addendum = null
const acts.change = [act1];
console.log( acts.change.concat(addendum?.changedActions) );
```

Outputs `[act1, null]` rather than the expected `[act1]`. Am I misusing the null-conditional operator or is

```js
console.log( addendum ? acts.change.concat(addendum?.changedActions) : acts.change )
```

the best/briefest way to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: Do you mean the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)? Based on the semantics documented there, I wouldn't expect this to do anything other than pass `undefined` to `.concat` as its second argument, right?

Comment: Your second version is easier to read than the hypothetical version, anyway; going further I'd actually suggest an `if`/`else` statement pair. _Make your code easy to read first._

Comment: you could also do `acts.change.concat(addendum?.changedActions??""))`

Comment: `const acts.change` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @emrhzc Shouldn't it be `??[]`?

Comment: you got the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to make `concat()` ignore the argument. So you need to replace an undefined argument with an empty array in order to to concatenate nothing.

You can use the [null coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator in additional to conditional chaining:

```
addendum?.changedActions??[]
```

To further reduce the syntax, use ES6 ellipsis instead of calling `concat()`.

```
console.log([...acts.change, ...addendum?.changedActions??[]])
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks, friends, testing revealed that

```js
acts.change.concat(addendum?.changedActions??[]))
```

is the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: The more readable (and backwards compatible and performant) form would be `if(addendum) acts.change.concat(addendum.changedActions);`.